# EasyMock - Mock a class having other class object and .class as parameters

Tags: java, mocking, easymock

I am currently using EasyMock and trying a lot to fix my problem.

Let me explain you in the simple words, Totally I have 5 classes.

- Main.java
- A.java
- B.java
- C.java
- Result.java

From Main.java I am calling a method of A.java

```
objectOfA.someMethod("String",objectofB, C.class);
```

While Mocking...

```
expect( objectofA.someMethod( "given some String", Prepared some dummy object of B and passing , C.class ) ).andReturn( objectofResult ).anyTimes();
```

While I am running the application its giving AssersionError.

My Questions:

1. In the expect method > while calling objectofA.someMethod(), In the second parameter I am creating one dummy object of B, actually B has nearly 10 variables and among them one will be generated randomly, but while creating the dummy object I am giving some value of my own, will it be a problem ?
2. 3rd parameter, we have to pass C.class, How can we pass this ?
3. Finally in andReturn() I am passing objectofResult class, do I need to parpare the dummy object of Result in this case ? because in Result.java we have nearly 20 variables and its really difficult for me to guess the values.

In Result.java I just need to verify a single String variable value.

I am trying a lot since 3 days, can someone help me to fix this please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't tell you what is "right" for your code; because we don't have the full picture (and you should not expect that somebody will spent his time to dive into all your code if you would have posted it).

So, for your questions:

1) +2) I think you are getting it backward. The point is: you tell EasyMock about the invocations that your "code under test" should make.

This means: you tell EasyMock that someMethod should be invoked; and EasyMock will check if the actual invocation matches your specification.

So, it really depends on your implementation of your B class. If the B object that your actual code passes with someMethod() is **equal** to the B object that you provide in the EasyMock staging; than all is fine. But if they are not equal, then EasyMock will complain. You can change that for example by using matchers, like

```
EasyMock.expect(
  yourMock.someMethod(
    eq("string to match"), anyObject(B.class), ...)
```

(where eq, anyObject being static methods in EasyMock).

But the problem there is: if you use matchers; you have to use matchers on **all** your arguments. And (for the moment); I am not aware of a matcher that would work for the "class" argument. So, for now I can only advise to do something like:

```
EasyMock.expect(
  yourMock.someMethod("string to match", expectedB, C.class))
```

where "expectedB" is a B object that you setup in advance; so that it matches what is created by your code under test. In order to get there, you will have to make sure that your B class as a "good" equals() method.

3) Again; the question what your "dummy result" is capable of; depends on how your code under test will be using it.

Example: assume that your code under test will invoke .toString() on that result object. Then you might want to prepare for that; for example by making that result object ... be another mock; that expects calls to toString().

Long story short: you use EasyMock to specify everything that you expect to "come out" of your class under test; and to control everything that "flows into" that class under test.

Comment: Thanks for your reply friend..I have tried to do the changes as you suggested..and while changing 3rd parameter notNull(C.class) its showing...  Type mismatch: cannot convert from C to Class<T> Error.

Comment: Yes, you are correct; notNull(Class<T>) will return a T ... not T.class. I will update my answer to that. And at least for now: I am lost, too. Not sure if/how to match on a certain class.

Comment: Actually I have prepared expectedB object, in that I have a field called reqId, this will be generated randomly for every new request. But In my created expectedB object I have given some value of my own,  as reqId will be generated rendomly, I am not able to match expectedB with the original one (which will be generated at the time of running the app).

Comment: As a result its giving unexpected method call exception.

Comment: I have tried to hard code the original value with the one I am using in my mock object, but still getting unexpected method call exception

Comment: You get "unexpected method" invocations when the actual invocation doesn't met the specification. I told you what you need to now: the expectedB must be **equal** to the one that is passed in. And another hint: consider if you can rework your design. Ideally, methods should have 0 to 1 parameter; and two is like the absolute maximum anyway. So   you could (seriously) consider if you can change your API so that you have less parameters.

Comment: Glad to hear; feel free to "accept" the answer then ;-)

Comment: One last help bro..., how to deal with super class method ? when the flow reach functionxyz(someClass); its giving nullpointer. functionxyz(-) is a method from super class of Main.java

Comment: So A extends Main? In any case, any exception in your test case can mean two things: a) "your setup" is incomplete ... b) you discovered a bug. If functionxyz wants to do so something on some object that is null; then you probably never initialized that object. Hard to say without more code ... but basically we should stop here; we are getting into a "discussion" already.

Comment: yeah you are correct, functionxyz doing something on some object that is null;   I am not sure how to initialize that object. I have tried creating a mock for that object (which currently showing null) and stuck here... I don't know where to pass this object with setField(). Its a question of how to mock the object in the super class. If know can u please suggest.

Comment: I don't know your design. Simply spoken, you want to read about dependency injection; and how to use it. Worst case: write up a new question, and provide enough source code to understand what is going on!